# Force intcomma to use points instead of commas, L10N has to be set to False

Tags: django, django-1.6

Premise: I can not change `USE_L10N = False` in my settings.py for various reasons

How can I make `{{ 1000000|intcomma }}` output `1.000.000` instead of `1,000,000`?

Comment: I havent tried this out, but can you consider using the `{% localize %}` block tags?

Comment: I thank you for the hint, but at the end we finished enabling L10N and intcomma did the job then.